# angularjs 1.5.x click not working in IE 11 select option box

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two select boxes, when clicking an item in one I send it to the second box. This works fine on chrome but IE 11 does not register the `ng-click` as expected. One similar question I read mentioned `pointer-events` but when I changed it to `auto` as bootstrap has it as `none` I did not see a change.

```
                        <select id="availableStuff">
                        <option ng-repeat="a in aList"
                                ng-click="move1(a)">
                            {{a}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="selectedStuff">
                        <option ng-repeat="b in bList" ng-click="move2(b)">
                            {{b}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdspLChpBT4j5kp2X1mb?p=preview)

Using angularjs 1.5.x and bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: @downvoters , you went through and downvoted question and both answers. Any reason?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known compatible issue, use `ng-options` for cross-browser behaviors

```
<select size='8'
        ng-model="selectedOption" 
        ng-options="a as a for a in aList" 
        ng-change="move1(selectedOption)">
</select>
```

Comment: edited to fix ng-options format, testing and if it works i will accept. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I would not use a select in this case. A lot of users dont expert this behavior with a select. Instead I would add to styled  list beside each other. Using ex bootstraps list groups. Then you could use fontawesome arrow icons to bind the move click event. There is no compability problems there. And it would be intuitive for the end user